# How does a muscle grow step-by-step?

Tags: nutrition, muscle, supplements, anatomy

I am trying to understand how a muscle such as the bicep grows step-by-step. For example (but not limited to):

1. How nutrients line up?
2. Which are essentials?
3. What exactly do they do?

It's hard to make sense of the **process** when potein, bcaas, glutamine, amino acids, complexe carbs, simple carbs, con-cret creatine, mono creatine, calories, weight gainer, pre, intra, post workout supplements all seem to *promote lean muscle*.

I'm looking for a **physiological** answer.

Comment: Wow, I think this question is asking a lot of things here. A high-level answer (with enough details) would probably suffice, but keep in mind that questions that require an entire book (note that this is in the [faq#dontask]) shouldn't really be asked.

Comment: I've been a SE user for quite some time now and I've seen long and high quality answer before :), take a look: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11234/how-does-hacking-work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a relatively deep article [here](http://www.simplyshredded.com/muscle-growth-part-1-the-science-behind-why-and-how-does-a-muscle-grow-and-get-stronger.html)

I hope it can help you

Comment: Can you summarize the points of that article here instead of just providing a link?

Comment: sorry my english is not as good to make some shortened version of relatively scientific article

Comment: You could at least try.